# How to customize email template of Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, email, templates

how can I edit the email template that is being sent when resetting passwords or verifying the email addresses. [Image of the sample email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EN7vw.png)

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/passwords#resetting-views

Answer (score 2):

Import email template using the following command

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-mail
```

Then you can edit your html/text template in this folder

```
resources/views/vendor/mail
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mail#customizing-the-components

Answer (score 0):

You should change the default Laravel sendPasswordResetNotification method on your User model.

Because the lines are come from Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\ResetPassword.php. Never you must change this facade. If you do it you can lost changes during an update of Laravel.

Instead of it do this, add the following to your your User model.

```
use App\Notifications\PasswordReset; // Or the location that you store your notifications (this is default).

/**
 * Send the password reset notification.
 *
 * @param  string  $token
 * @return void
 */
public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
{
    $this->notify(new PasswordReset($token));
}
```

Create create that notification:

```
php artisan make:notification PasswordReset
```

And example of this notification's content:

```
/**
 * The password reset token.
 *
 * @var string
 */
public $token;

/**
 * Create a new notification instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct($token)
{
    $this->token = $token;
}

/**
 * Get the notification's delivery channels.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return array
 */
public function via($notifiable)
{
    return ['mail'];
}

/**
 * Build the mail representation of the notification.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
 */
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    return (new MailMessage)
        ->line('You are receiving this email because we received a password reset request for your account.') // Here are the lines you can safely override
        ->action('Reset Password', url('password/reset', $this->token))
        ->line('If you did not request a password reset, no further action is required.');
}
```

Comment: How can I add images and add some style?

Comment: You can create new blade in resources folder. Please follow this link to learn how can send this blade:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mail#view-data

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has internal templates for emails and notifications. **Notification templates are integrated into the email templates**. Thus, a notification template serves as a message component of an mail. It is important to note that `message` templates are part of `mail` templates.

To manage, edit, or customize Laravel email templates, they must first be published. This can be done by running the following Artisan commands:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-mail 
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-notifications
```

Laravel will place these files in the following locations:

```
/resources/views/vendor/mail
/resources/views/vendor/notifications
```

At this point, a custom email HTML template can be integrated into `/resources/views/vendor/mail/html`, which contains files for:

- `layout.blade.php` - base layout
- `header.blade.php` - header
- `footer.blade.php` - footer
- `button.blade.php` - button/action
- `message.blade.php` - **email body** (notification text)

The `/resources/views/vendor/notifications` directory contains a single file, `email.blade.php`, used for notifications. In most cases, it does not require modification.

It is important to note that **indentation or tabs should not be added to these Blade files**, as it will transform the HTML into plain text.​

### Example

Laravel provides the ability for user email verification **through a customized URL that utilizes a user's UUID rather than internal ID**. This functionality is documented in the official Laravel documentation.

Make an own notification class via this command:

```
php artisan make:notification VerifyEmail
```

The command will create `VerifyEmail.php` at `app/Notifications` folder. Let's update it:

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;

class VerifyEmail extends \Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\VerifyEmail
{
    protected function buildMailMessage($url)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
            ->subject('my subject')
            ->line('text line 1')
            ->action('please verify!', $url)
            ->line('text line 2');
    }

    //$notifiable = User model object
    protected function verificationUrl($notifiable)
    {
        if (static::$createUrlCallback) {
            return call_user_func(static::$createUrlCallback, $notifiable);
        }

        return URL::temporarySignedRoute(
            'verification.verify',
            Carbon::now()->addMinutes(Config::get('auth.verification.expire', 60)),
            [
                'uuid' => $notifiable->uuid,//custom User model field
                'hash' => sha1($notifiable->getEmailForVerification())
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

Edit User model `/app/Models/User.php`:

1. Model has to implement `\Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail` interface
2. Model has to use trait `Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable`
3. You have to override `sendEmailVerificationNotification()` method with a custom notification class in use

User model class code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    use Notifiable;

    /*some code*/

    public function sendEmailVerificationNotification()
    {
        $this->notify(new \App\Notifications\VerifyEmail);
    }
}
```

Also you have to modify `verification.verify` route at `/routes/web.php`. Just like that.

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\EmailVerificationRequest;
// {uuid} instead of {id}
Route::get('/email/verify/{uuid}/{hash}', function (EmailVerificationRequest $request) {
    $request->fulfill();
    return redirect('/home');
})->middleware(['auth', 'signed'])->name('verification.verify');
```